# Is it mathematically possible to break a number into 2 parts using information you used to combine them?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Im not a math person. Here goes.

Bob has 2 numbers A & B.
Bob used a detailed process which takes `A` & `B` as inputs, and results `C`
The process does not store A or B.

```
A (process) B = C
```

Can Jack use the detailed step-by-step `process` to convert `C` back into `A` and `B` ?

Is  it possible to define a set of rules such that the above is possible?

Comment: "combine" ? The way to add $A$ and $B$ to compute $C=A+B$ is obviously univocal, but having $C$, there is more than one possibility of $A,B$ such that $C=A+B$.

Comment: forgive me if i used the word `combine`... I meant the process took 2 numbers as inputs and gave C as the output. Therefore, it does not have to be addition. The process can be literally anything.

Comment: In certain very restrictive settings and scenarios, some certain "processes" that take two inputs and give an output (*what should more correctly be described as a function, e.g. a function from $X\times Y$ to $Z$ mapping $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$*) can in fact be invertible and so knowing the output will give you a way to find the two inputs regardless what the output actually was.  Such a function would be called "invertible" or "bijective."  There are of course many examples of functions which are *not* invertible however.  The example above of $f(x,y)=x+y$ over the reals is one such example.

Comment: An example of a function which is invertible that takes a pair of inputs to produce an output would be the function $f~:~\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ mapping $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a(2b+1)$.  So, if I told you the output was $12$ for instance, I could tell you the only input that gives that is $(2,1)$.  As for "*Is it possible to define a set of rules such that the above is possible*" you seem to be asking for sufficient conditions for a function to be known to be bijective.  Much work has been done on this question for various contexts, especially in Linear Algebra for linear functions.

Comment: is there some concrete example? You guys seem to have the answer, but I cant speak all the math-func-language.  Lets say i know C = 100 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most situations, no. The `(process)` can't be addition or multiplication since you can't find the summands or factors knowing just the sum or product.

There are special cases. For example, if you know each of the numbers is an integer and $A$ and $B$ are less than $1000$ and you let
$$
C = 1000A + B
$$
then knowing $C$ tells you both $A$ and $B$.

If you have some particular previous question that led to this one, ask that question.

**Edit**. Your comment suggests that a solution like the one I proposed above may work. If $A$ and $B$ are both known to be integers less than some bound $M$ then with
$$
C = AM + B
$$
you know $B = C \% M$ and $A = (C-B)/M$.
This works because  $C$ is a two digit number in base $M$ with digits $A$ and $B$.

**Edit** in answer to comment.

"$C = 100$" is  not all the information. To find $A$ and $B$ you need to know both $C$ and the *a priori* bound $M$ (independent of $A$ and $B$).

For example, if $C=100$ and $M=50$ then $100$ in base $50$ is the two digit number "$20$" since $100 = 2 \times 50 + 0$ so $A=2$ and $B=0$.

Comment: Even finding *one* process that works for all real numbers $A, B$ is pretty hard, to the point that it was quite a surprise to Cantor when he found one. :-)

Comment: `if you know each of the numbers  and  is less than 1000... then knowing  tells you both  and .` -- This is exactly what I want. But i am just trying to decrypt your math-speak. Taking a couple mins... Trying to get a concrete example

Comment: is there some concrete example? You guys seem to have the answer, but I cant speak all the math-func-language.  Lets say i know C = 100 ?

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The classic method here takes any number of numbers $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$,… raises primes to those powers and multiplies them: $$RESULT=2^A 3^B 5^C 7^D 11^E…$$

The reverse process is the prime factorisation of $RESULT$.

In the way I have described it, the numbers all need to be greater than zero, but it is easy enough to add 1 to each of them before multiplication. One more minor adjustment, and you have found a way of packing *any* finite sequence of numbers, *of any [finite] length*, into a single number. Which proves that there are "as many" finite sequences of numbers as there are numbers.